# Apache failover BalanceMember

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, failover

An interesting question crept up on me when I made the following configuration (names and IPs are fictitious).

Background:

```
route 1 - 10.10.10.10 is an IPSec tunnel
route 2 - 20.20.20.20 to the Internet
original service URL (nginx) - https://testscb.com - work
Virtual apache server (another machine, not mine) DNS - testscb.local.com
I want to make sure that if the main route 1 is unavailable, all traffic goes to route 2. And when the communication channel is restored, it goes back to route 1.
```

My settings:

/etc/hosts

```
10.10.10.10 testw1.com testscb1.com
20.20.20.20 testw2.com testscb2.com
```

port 443 open

```
traceroute to testscb1.com (10.10.10.10), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
7  testscb1.com (10.10.10.10)  2.955 ms  2.985 ms  2.839 ms

traceroute to testscb2.com (20.20.20.20), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
4  testscb2.com (20.20.20.20)  1.731 ms  1.834 ms  2.244 ms
```

/etc/httpd/virtual_host/testscb.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName testscb.local.com

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

ProxyHCExpr ok234 {%{REQUEST_STATUS} =~ /^[234]/}
#ProxyHCExpr gdown {%{REQUEST_STATUS} =~ /^[5]/}

#  BalanceMember in /etc/hosts
  <Proxy "balancer://testscb">
    BalancerMember https://testscb1.com hcmethod=HEAD hcexpr=ok234 hcinterval=20 hcuri=/test hcfails=4 hcpasses=4 
    BalancerMember https://testscb2.com hcmethod=HEAD hcexpr=ok234 hcinterval=20 hcuri=/test hcfails=4 hcpasses=4 status=+H
    ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
    ProxySet lbmethod=heartbeat
  </Proxy>

    ProxyPass "/" "balancer://testscb/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "balancer://testscb/"

<Location "/">
    ProxyPass "https://testscb.com/"
    ProxyPassReverse "https://testscb.com/"
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from All
</Location>

LogLevel debug
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/testscb-error_log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/testscb-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

apachectl graceful

httpd.service Active: active (running)

Tests: I use curl from apache server machine.

curl -v -k https://testscb1.com/

```
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< 
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host testscb1.com left intact
```

curl -v -k https://testscb2.com/

```
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< 
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host testscb2.com left intact
```

tcpdump while using curl confirms that the exchange is in progress.

Sending requests via curl from my computer.

curl -v -k http://testscb.local.com/

```
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< 
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host testscb.local.com left intact
```

But I noticed that route 2 is used. Although it should be standby (see in tcpdump).

Further even more interestin. I'm turning around the route to test the communication link failure:

```
ip ro add 20.20.20.20 via 127.0.0.1
```

Now curl -v -k https://testscb2.com/ gives an error "port 443: Connection timed out".

And when I send a request from my computer curl -v -k http://testscb.local.com/

I also receive "port 443: Connection timed out".

I don't understand why route 2 is involved, it feels like route 1 doesn't exist for apache.

I would be very grateful for tips. Thank you.